# Unable to get last_insert_id() from MySQL Compose DB

Tags: java, mysql, ibm-cloud, spring-batch, compose-db

My spring-batch application generates the following error while trying to get "last_insert_id()" from Compose for MySQL database privided by IBM bluemix:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain last_insert_id(); nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: The table does not comply with the requirements by an external plugin.] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: The table does not comply with the requirements by an external plugin.
```

Comment: I'd like to help, but need more clarification. Are there any error codes? Could you please provide the full stack trace? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately no error code. Here is the stack trace:

Comment: Have you seen other posts with similar issues?  E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39828072/1033422

Comment: at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
...
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.MySQLMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(MySQLMaxValueIncrementer.java:102)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.nextLongValue(AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.java:128)